# Project Euler Problem 338

Tags: number-theory, combinatorics, algorithms, project-euler

I'm stuck on Project Euler [problem 338](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=338). This is a [cross post from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223392/project-euler-problem-338) where I initially posted, however, it was suggested that I post it here too since the problem mostly relies on math. The following is work towards a solution I have made.

Let's denote a rectangle with width and height $x$ and $y$ respectively $(x,y)$. To form new rectangles you can consider cutting a kind of stairway down the diagonal (as is shown in in the problem description) with d steps. But to form a new rectangle the following must hold: $d|x$ and either $(d-1)|y$ or $(d+1)|y$. The new rectangle then becomes either (${x(d-1)}\over{d}$, ${yd}\over{d-1}$) or (${x(d+1)}\over{d}$, ${yd}\over{d+1}$). Obviously the new rectangle's area is the same as the old rectangle's.

That was enough to confirm that $G(10)=55$ and $G(1000)=971745$ by looping through all relevant d and adding all new rectangles to a set being careful to count $(x,y)$ and $(y,x)$ only once.

The main issue with this method is that it's possible to make a new rectangle in two different ways. For example, $(9,8)$ can transform into both $(6,12)$ and $(12,6)$ with $d=3$ and either $d-1$ or $d+1$ dividing $y$. Or another example of $(4,4)$ transforms into both $(2,8)$ and $(8,2)$ with $d=2$ and $d=1$ respectively.

I was then lucky enough to read [this blog post](https://jaroslawpawlak.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/problem-338-4/). It removes the need to check for duplicates by searching for one of the sides instead.

```
def F(w, h):
    if w&1 and h&1: return 0
    if w<h: w,h = h,w

    r = 0
    x = 1
    while x**2 <= w*h:
        if (w*h)%x!=0 or x==h:
            x += 1
            continue

        if w%(w-x)==0 or x%(x-h)==0:
            r += 1

        x += 1

    return r

def G(N):
    s = 0
    for w in range(1, N+1):
        for h in range(1, w+1):
            s += F(w,h)

    return s
```

G(10<sup>12</sup>) would require far too long to solve regardless of how fast F is though. I think it's necessary to either use some kind of sieving algorithm where we loop through all x < 10<sup>12</sup> counting how many (w,h) satisfy h $\le$ w $\le$ 10<sup>12</sup>, x|(wh), x $\ne$ h and (w-x)|w or (x-h)|x $\implies$ (x-h)|h.

I think an O(n<sup>2/3</sup>) algorithm must be possible... but I'm stuck here!

**Edit**: On the suggestion I've checked for a few basic patterns in G(n). If gcd(a,b)=1, G(ab) $\ne$ G(a)G(b) in general (for instance G(2)=1, G(5)=8, G(10)=55). In fact it seems G(ab) $\ge$ G(a)G(b).

Looking at G(2<sup>n</sup>) I have noticed it grows exponentially but very little else. It doesn't show any obvious patterns modulo small primes. The same goes for G(5<sup>n</sup>). In general, G(k<sup>n</sup>) grows about as fast as k<sup>2n</sup>.

**Edit2**: Here's the table of F(w,h) for $w$, $h$ $\le$ 10:

```
    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

 1  0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
 2  0 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 2 2
 3  0 1 0 1 0 1 0 2 0 2
 4  1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 3 2
 5  0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0
 6  1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 3
 7  0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
 8  1 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 2
 9  0 2 0 3 0 1 0 2 0 2
10  1 2 2 2 0 3 1 2 2 1
```

It's symmetrical about the diagonal since F(w,h)=F(h,w).

Comment: I see no reason to think it is possible to count by brute force. My first try would be to see if whenever $\gcd(a,b)=1,$ does it follow that $G(ab) = G(a) G(b).$ I have no idea, by the way. Then I would check low powers and see if I could find a pattern in $G(2^k)$ and then $G(5^m).$

Comment: Alright, I don't think I want to write any programs for this. Could you please post a little table of all the separate F(w,h) with 1 <= h <= w <= 10? Evidently the interesting relationships occur there, not in the cumulative function G.

Comment: I voted to close because I do think that it is a very bad idea to have a collection of project Euler solutions here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a project euler problem

Answer (score -1):

By analyzing $\sum_{i=1}^{N} F(i,N)$ and comparing it with $\sum_{i|N} \lfloor \frac{N}{i+1} \rfloor + \lfloor \frac{N}{i-1} \rfloor$, I observe that $\sum_{i=1}^{N}F(i,N)$ may be equal to $$\sum_{i|N}( \lfloor \frac{N}{i+1} \rfloor + \lfloor \frac{N}{i-1} \rfloor+1) - \sum_{(ij)|N}1 - \sum_{i(i+1)|N}1.$$ Numerical results of small cases agree with the formula, and formal proof is appreciated.